# Struggling with nodes list and templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nlp

It's me, again but this time my question is interesting. I work on an NLP project and i need to extract syntactic dependencies. Check my xml file before. It's gonna be clearer.

```
<items>
<item type="forme" pos="86"><f>et</f><c>J</c><l>et</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>B</a><a>W</a><a>_</a><a>-</a><a>89.635342168126</a><a>91.64462185594235</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>mm</a><a>433.8949999999997</a><a>613.0525000000002</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>motherless_mm</a><a>motherless</a><a>mm</a><a>U</a><a>U_mm</a><a>U_weak_mm</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>U</a><a>U_weak</a><a>U_weak_mm</a><a>weak</a><a>mm</a><a>16.864728</a><a>17.298623</a><a>(IU:B)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:U)_(GR:U)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:U)_(PER:I)_(GR:U)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="87"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="88"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>PARA_DISFL(92)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>PARA_DISFL(92)</a><a>SUB_INHERITED(94)</a><a>-</a><a>U</a><a>I</a><a>B</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>89.78229983184981</a><a>90.9450769686341</a><a>U</a><a>U_ml</a><a>ml</a><a>559.0779999999995</a><a>446.97400000000084</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>B</a><a>B_mhL2</a><a>lone-dis-strong_mhL2</a><a>lone-dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>B</a><a>B_mhL2</a><a>B_dis-strong_mhL2</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>B</a><a>B_dis-strong</a><a>B_dis-strong_mhL2</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>17.298623</a><a>17.857701</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="89"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="90"><f>euh</f><c>I</c><l>euh</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>ROOT</a><a>ROOT</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>B</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>U</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>91.0917299634017</a><a>88.32560736761792</a><a>U</a><a>U_mL</a><a>mL</a><a>667.027000000001</a><a>365.74324999999953</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone-dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>17.857701</a><a>18.524728</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:U)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="91"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="92"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>SUB(94)</a><a>SUB(94)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>L</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>90.76577375975249</a><a>89.37667027198918</a><a>U</a><a>U_mhl2</a><a>mhl2</a><a>240.000000000002</a><a>436.54499999999973</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone-dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>18.524728</a><a>18.764728</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:I)_(GR:I)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:I)_(PER:I)_(GR:I)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="93"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="94"><f>continue</f><c>V</c><l>continuer</l><a>B</a><a>indicative</a><a>present</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>DEP(86)</a><a>DEP(86)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>L</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>0</a><a>H</a><a>92.42666896088915</a><a>93.38822556873673</a><a>U</a><a>U_mh</a><a>mh</a><a>653.0169999999985</a><a>200.0187499999999</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone-dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>dis-strong</a><a>mhL2</a><a>18.764728</a><a>19.93782</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="95"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="96"><f>je</f><c>Cl</c><l>je</l><a>B</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>SUB(98)</a><a>SUB(98)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>B</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>0</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>92.31503521460044</a><a>93.43435942977976</a><a>U</a><a>U_hm</a><a>hm</a><a>80.00000000000185</a><a>318.27299999999957</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>B</a><a>B_hh</a><a>lone_hh</a><a>lone</a><a>hh</a><a>B</a><a>B_hh</a><a>B_strong_hh</a><a>strong</a><a>hh</a><a>B</a><a>B_strong</a><a>B_strong_hh</a><a>strong</a><a>hh</a><a>19.93782</a><a>20.01782</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:B)_(GR:B)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:B)_(PER:I)_(GR:B)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="97"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
<item type="forme" pos="98"><f>continue</f><c>V</c><l>continuer</l><a>B</a><a>indicative</a><a>present</a><a>1</a><a>sg</a><a>-</a><a>PARA_DISFL(94)</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>PARA_DISFL(94)</a><a>DEP_INHERITED(86)</a><a>-</a><a>L</a><a>I</a><a>I</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>O</a><a>S</a><a>0</a><a>-</a><a>92.48276610196193</a><a>92.52747870666991</a><a>U</a><a>U_mh</a><a>mh</a><a>297.8790000000018</a><a>289.99999999999915</a><a>$L1</a><a>-</a><a>I</a><a>-</a><a>hl</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>lone</a><a>hh</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hh</a><a>L</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>strong</a><a>hh</a><a>20.01782</a><a>20.645699</a><a>(IU:I)_(PER:I)_(PAQ:L)_(GR:L)</a><a>(ASNUC:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PRN:O)_(PER:I)</a><a>(PON:O)_(PAQ:L)_(PER:I)_(GR:L)</a></item>
<item type="delim" pos="99"><f> </f><c>BLANK</c><l>BLANK</l><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a><a>-</a></item>
```

My task is to catch all items with a[7] contains (SUB). You can see there is a numero. It matches with the attribute of an item (pos) and i need to catch it. I precise that i have to have the forms of words (it's f node). But the most important, when i managed to grab my two words (the SUB one on the pos one), i need to sort them. I have to count words, check the most frequently world, sort by categories (it's c nodes). The problem is i have to work with my 2 items nodes and all other i'll could find it. But i struggle to manage with nodes. For example here, the item with pos attribute 92 has a[7] = SUB and i need to grab the item with attribute pos = 94 because it's SUB(94). So here i have to catch the word "je" and "continue". Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
      
    <xsl:template match="/">

        (; i need a variable here to grab the items nodes, all my items from the xsl:template match="item :)
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//item"/>
        
    </xsl:template>   
    
    <xsl:template match="item">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="current()[@type='forme'][contains(a[7],'SUB')]">
            <xsl:variable name="sub_index" select= "@pos"/>
            <xsl:variable name="gouv_index" select="replace(a[7], '\w+\((\d+)\)', '$1')"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number($sub_index &lt; number($gouv_index))">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current()/f, ' ',current()/c,' ', following-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/f,' ', following-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/c)"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(current()/f, ' ',current()/c, ' ', preceding-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/f, ' ', preceding-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/c)"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm looking for a method to get out these item nodes outside the template capturing item. I tried so many times with variable, sequences, elements but i don't have a node list with each of my SUB items + the pos item. Initially, i don't know how to connect these two nodes. And put them in a list of nodes is impossible for me. I don't want an entire code, just the way to accede to my item list outside the template.
Here is my output on the entire file :

```
 je Cl remonte V
je Cl traverse V
je Cl continue V
je Cl continue V
qui Qu est V
il Cl a V
je Cl reprends V
je Cl crois V
c Cl est V
je Cl sais V
c Cl est V
c Cl est V
je Cl vais V
je Cl retrouve V
je Cl vais V
je Cl vais V
je Cl vais V
c Cl est V
je Cl vais V
je Cl crois V
c Cl est V
je Cl vais V
je Cl vais V
je Cl souviens V
je Cl vais V
je Cl vais V
j Cl arrive V
il Cl a V
ils Cl sont V
je Cl suis V
tu Cl vois V
tu Cl continues V
tu Cl traverses V
tu Cl arrives V
c Cl est V
tu Cl passes V
tu Cl montes V
tu Cl passes V
il Cl a V
tu Cl arrives V
tu Cl rentres V
tu Cl arrives V
c Cl est V
je Cl crois V
ça Pro sera V
tu Cl traverses V
tu Cl arrives V
c Cl est V
tu Cl descends V
c Cl est V
qui Qu descend V
tu Cl passes V
tu Cl passes V
c Cl est V
il Cl semble V
tu Cl montes V
tu Cl arrives V
c Cl est V
il Cl a V
c Cl est V
programme N comporte V
nous Cl proposons V
qui Qu dormaient V
prédécesseurs N avaient V
l Cl retrouve V
vous Cl semblez V
c Cl est V
nous Cl acceptons V
nous Cl sommes V
qui Qu a V
combats N jalonnent V
c Cl est V
nous Cl avons V
nous Cl avons V
nous Cl avons V
```

But i need to sort it with the most frequent words, sorting by categories (in fact, the file is far bigger so it could be some changes). I need a method to work with nodes list. It's gonna easier for me to sort and count after. I can't do everything in my <xsl:template match="item"> I just want a solution to can manipulate my items from the template to the "main" template (with key, sequences, attribute-set... i don't know)
Thx for your attention.

Comment: Your questions are way too wide. Please try to break down the problem to basic blocks and ask a simpler question aimed on only the part that are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

As in stated my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67193030/3710053
<xsl:for-each select="current() has no use, since the context of your match is one item.

I tried to understand your goal, so maybe this is direction you can use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="itemsToSort" as="element(itemToSort)*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item[@type='forme'][contains(a[7],'SUB')]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$itemsToSort">
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <itemToSort>
      <xsl:variable name="sub_index" select= "@pos"/>
      <xsl:variable name="gouv_index" select="replace(a[7], '\w+\((\d+)\)', '$1')"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($sub_index &lt; number($gouv_index))">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(current()/f, ' ',current()/c,' ', following-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/f,' ', following-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/c)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(current()/f, ' ',current()/c, ' ', preceding-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/f, ' ', preceding-sibling::item[@pos = number($gouv_index)]/c)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </itemToSort>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="itemToSort">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```